# Is there a way to update Arduino uno Over The Air

Tags: arduino-uno, remote-control, networking, network

I have the Arduino uno with a Ethernet W5100 Shield and would like to remotely sketches.  Is there a way to update Arduino uno over the air?  If not, is there a wired network arduino solution that will allow update over the air.

I've done this on the esp8266 using there tools but I can't find one for the Uno.

Thanks

Comment: Also asked at: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=511708 If you're going to do that then please be considerate enough to add links to the other places you cross posted. This will let us avoid wasting time due to duplicate effort and also help others who have the same questions and find your post to discover all the relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with WiFi, nor with Ethernet. People have managed it with Bluetooth, but only because it can create a transparent serial bridge. The bootloader only talks serial, so you have to use something that is serial to program it.

The only possible way is to use another WiFi (or Ethernet) device, such as the ESP8266, to act as a serial bridge to connect the Arduino's serial port (and reset signal) to your computer over WiFi. A bit of a waste of an ESP8266 since that is then the sole task it would have (unless you craft a far more complex sketch for the ESP8266 to allow it to do other things as well).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  What about any of the other arduino family or compatibles?

Comment: You would need a board that a) has WiFi built in, and b) has a bootloader capable of operating with it (or other similar facilities). I don't know of an Arduino that does that. I do know of the ESP8266 though (and so do you). Oh, and I have done it using an ESP8266 connected to an Arduino to bootload the Arduino.

Comment: There is a sketch I created for bootloading Arduino-like boards using an ESP8266 as a serial bridge (https://github.com/MajenkoProjects/WiFiSerialDTR). It does the reset for you using a simulated DTR signal, and (though not properly tested yet) also should implement RFC2217 for baud rate changing. Note: the ESP8266 is then *only* for bootloading and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ariadne bootloader project](https://github.com/per1234/Ariadne-Bootloader) enables upload over Ethernet to AVR boards with Ethernet shield.